# Category of paths

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, category-theory

let $P(X)$ be the category of paths on a topological space. How do I decide if $$P(X \sqcup Y) = P(X) \sqcup P(Y)$$ where $\sqcup$ is the topological sum and disjoint union?

The definition of category of paths is found here at page 205: https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf

Comment: What do you mean by "the category of paths"?  The fundamental groupoid?  And, have you thought about what a path in the space $X\sqcup Y$ can be?

Comment: @EricWofsey No, I mean the category of all paths between points in $X$

Comment: How is that a category?  What are your objects and morphisms, precisely, and what is composition?

Comment: the category has the set $X$ as its set of objects, and for any $x,y \in X$, the set $PX(x,y)$ is the set of paths in $X$ from $x$ to $y$. Composition is composition of paths

Comment: Are you taking paths up to homotopy?  Or parametrizing them by intervals of arbitrary lengths?  Or something else?

Comment: no not taking paths up to homotopy, just any path on its own

Comment: Composition of paths is not associative, by the usual definitions...you really need to state your exact definitions in full.

Comment: @EricWofsey https://groupoids.org.uk/pdffiles/topgrpds-e.pdf page 205

Comment: @EricWofsey Paths here are modeled I think on [0,L]. The OP's statement is (in probably any coherent interpretation) true.

Comment: @Eric: sure it is, once you allow paths of arbitrary length: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Moore+path+category

Comment: I wonder why topology texts make things more difficult (in my view) for students by NOT using paths as maps $[0,r] \to X$ for various $r \geqslant 0$. Actually it is also   conveient to  follow John Moore and say a path is a pair $(f,r)$ where $f:[0, \infty) \to X$ and $f$ is constant on $[r, \infty)$. Either way you get a **category** of paths. Why insist that $r=1$?.  .

Comment: Why insist that $r=1$?.  .Thinking of  paths as a _journeys_, one expects them to be of various length. In the maths, one has also to discuss reparametrization. See also the book by Crowell and Fox on Knot Theory.

Answer (score 1):

Both $X$ and $Y$ are clopen in the topology of $X\sqcup Y$, so any path in $X\sqcup Y$ must be either entirely contained in $X$ or entirely contained in $Y$.  It follows easily that $P(X\sqcup Y)$ is naturally isomorphic to $P(X)\sqcup P(Y)$.

Comment: Thank you. Is it also true that $P(X \times Y) = P(X) \times P(Y)$?

Comment: No: because of the varying "length".